# AKS Taking lot of time to pull image from our private docker repository

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

we have hosted our application on Azure AKS, we configured auto scaling for this deployment. Pods will automatically scales.

my problem here is, whenever AKS adds new nodes to cluster as part of autoscaling, our whole docker image needs to be downloaded to these new nodes. This is taking lot of time, and we are facing issues.

is there a way to use our own linux image, so that we can save the base image and new nodes does not required to download whole image.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can find the list of precached images on AKS nodes in the AKS docs somewhere (cant find it right now) and use one of the base images from that list alternatively you can use a daemonset to prepull needed images for each new now, this wont really speed up the process of scaling to a new node, but if you need to scale to an existing node that will be almost instant (so assuming node got scaled up not because your application needed to be scaled, but for some other reason).